# VBA Convert Negative Numbers to Postive

Tags: excel, vba

after the function that filters my results below zero, I have to write it as a positive result, i.e. without "-". However, I get the error "Object variable or With block not set" . What I doing wrong ?

```
Dim cl As Range
cl = wbMe.Sheets("pochodne").Range("T35").Copy
   If cl.Value < 0 Then
       cl.Value = -cl.Value
   End If
```

Comment: Remove the `.Copy` and use `Set cl = …`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects need to be "set", so try:

```vb
Dim wbMe    As Excel.Workbook
Dim cl      As Excel.Range

Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook

Set cl = wbMe.Worksheets("pochodne").Range("T35")
If cl.Value < 0 Then
   cl.Value = -cl.Value
End If
```

That works here.

Comment: No i got : Object required" error

Comment: Alternatively `cl.Value = Abs(cl.Value)` and removing the entire `If` will make it always positive too.